$\gcd(a,b)$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ vs $\mathbb{Z[\sqrt{2}]}$
Let $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$. How to prove that $\gcd(a,b)$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ is equal to $\gcd(a,b)$ in $\mathbb{Z[\sqrt{2}]}$ for any $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$?
My approach: When $a$ or $b$ is associated with 1, then $\gcd(a, b) = 1$, in both integral domains.
Similarly, when $a = 0$ or $b = 0$, then $gcd(0, b) = b$, $\gcd(a, 0) = a$, is also same in both integral domains.
For other cases let $c = \gcd(a, b) \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\bar{c} = \gcd(a, b) \in \mathbb{Z[\sqrt{2}]}$.
Because $\bar{c}$ is greatest common divisor of $a, b$, and $c$ divides both $a$ and $b$, it follows that $c$ divides $\bar{c}$ in $\mathbb{Z[\sqrt{2}]}$.
So $\bar{c} = c(e + \sqrt{2}f)$ for some $e, f \in \mathbb{Z}$.
I want to prove that $(e + \sqrt{2}f)$ is associated with 1, then $\gcd(a, b)$ will be equal in both integral domains for any $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$.
My approach was to divide it to 4 cases:

$e$ is associated with 1 and $f = 0$,
$e$ is not associated with 1 and $f = 0$,
$e$ is associated with 1 and $f \ne 0$,
$e$ is not associated with 1 and $f \ne 0$.

To prove the equality, I have to show that the last 3 points do not hold.
Let's denote $\nu$ the norm of $\mathbb{Z[\sqrt{2}]}$: $\nu(a + \sqrt{2}b) = |a^2 - 2b^2|$.
Let's start with the 3. point:
Because $c$ divides $\bar{c}$, it follows: $c^2 = \nu(c) \le \nu(\bar{c}) = c^2|(\pm1)^2 - 2f^2|$. It must follow that $|(\pm1)^2 - 2f^2| >= 1$, but $2f^2$ is always greater than $1$, so we get contradiction. (I have now realized, even this is not true, we don't get contradiction here.)
But I have problem with proving contradiction with points 2. and 4.
For example 2. point: $c^2 = \nu(c) \le \nu(\bar{c}) = c^2e^2$, here $e$ could be any integer for the inequality, so I don't get contradiction using this approach.
Is there a better, maybe easier, way to prove this equality? I appreciate any hints.
Thanks.

For your main question @meerkat you should consider a divisor of an integer in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ and apply the Galois map $\sqrt{2} \rightarrow -\sqrt{2}$ to prove that $\nu(\alpha)$ divides $a$ and $b$, so it divides $c$, for any prime $\alpha$ dividing $\overline{c}$ who is not in $\mathbb{Z}$.

@ChristopherNicol Thanks for the hint, but I don't get how $\nu(\bar{c})$ divide $\nu(a)$ and $\nu(b)$ implies, $\nu(\bar{c})$ divides $\nu(c)$ in $\mathbb{Z[\sqrt{2}]}$? What do you mean by applying Galois map? I know what Galois group is, just don't get it in this context.

I mean that if you have a prime $\alpha= e +f\cdot \sqrt{2}$ dividing $a$ and $b$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$, the Galois map sends it to $\beta =e-f\cdot \sqrt{2}$. But the Galois map fixes $a$ and $b$ as they are integers. So it induces a bijection on prime factors. So $\beta$ divides $a$ and $b$ with same multiplicity. By Gauss lemma $\nu(\alpha)=\alpha\beta$ divides $a$ and $b$.

@ChristopherNicol I am not sure I understand your argument fully, but intuitively what I get is that any prime number in $\mathbb{Z}$ if is reducible in $\mathbb{Z[\sqrt{2}]}$, then it's only in the form: $(a + b\sqrt{2})(a - b\sqrt{2})$, then I can understand equality of gcd in both domains. Because yes: $(a + b\sqrt{2})$ and $(a - b\sqrt{2})$ have the same norm so they both divide $a, b$ if $(a + b\sqrt{2})$ divides $a, b$. The problem to me is to prove that all prime numbers when they are reducible are in this form and not any other.

The $\gcd$ of two integers will also be a $\gcd$ in any extension ring, this is because $\Bbb Z$ is a principal ideal domain, so you have Bezout

@leoli1 Thanks. So $\mathbb{Z}$ is a principal ideal because it's an euclidean, and principal ideals have Bezout coefficients, i.e. $\gcd(a, b) = ax + by$ in $\mathbb{Z}$. But I don't see the connection with the first statement: "The gcd of two integers will also be a gcd in any extension ring".

Let $d=\gcd(a,b)$. Then $d = ax+by$ for some $x,y\in\Bbb Z$. Let $R$ be any extension ring of $\Bbb Z$. Then of course $d$ also divides $a,b$ in $R$ and if $c$ is a common divisor of $a,b$ in $R$, then $c\mid ax+by=d$, so $d$ is a gcd of $a,b$ in $R$.

@leoli1 ah makes sense. Thanks!

I will use the following claim, it is obvious and you probably already know it.
Claim Let $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ $(a\neq 0)$ such that $a$ divides $b$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$, then $a$ divides $b$ in $\mathbb{Z}$.
Proof : Indeed if $b=a\cdot (e+\sqrt{2} \cdot f) = ae + af \sqrt{2}$, as $b, af\in \mathbb{Z}$, we must have $f= 0$ so $a$ divides $b$ in $\mathbb{Z}$.
So in the sequel, if I say "$a$ divides $b$", either one of them is not in $\mathbb{Z}$ and I obviously take the division in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$, either both of them are integers, and the division is in $\mathbb{Z}$.
As $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ is a UFD (because it is euclidian), I can write the decomposition in prime factors for $a$ and $b$.
$$ a =\prod_\mathfrak{p} \mathfrak{p}^{a_i}, \ b =\prod_\mathfrak{p} \mathfrak{p}^{b_i} $$
and
$$ \overline{c} =\prod_\mathfrak{p} \mathfrak{p}^{\text{min}(a_i,b_i)}.$$
In this decomposition $2$ kinds of primes can occur.
Case $1$ : $\mathfrak{p} \in \mathbb{Z}$. As it is a prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$, it is also a prime in $\mathbb{Z}$. As  $\mathfrak{p}^{\text{min}(a_i,b_i)}$ divides $a$ and $b$ in $ \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$, it is also the case in $\mathbb{Z}$ due to my claim. So $\mathfrak{p}^{\text{min}(a_i,b_i)}$ divides $c$.
Case $2$ : $\mathfrak{p} \not\in \mathbb{Z}$. So I can write $\mathfrak{p}=e + f \cdot \sqrt{2}$ for $f \neq 0$. Now I introduce the Galois involution $\sigma$ of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$: $\sqrt{2} \rightarrow -\sqrt{2}$.
By assumption $\sigma(a)=a$ and $\sigma(b)=b$ as they are integers. But $\sigma(\mathfrak{p})\neq \mathfrak{p}$. Now $\sigma(\mathfrak{p})$ is also a prime and applying $\sigma$ (morphism of rings) to the prime decomposition shows that $\sigma(\mathfrak{p})$ divides $a$ (and $b$) with the same multiplicity.
So in $\overline{c}$ we have the factor $(\mathfrak{p}\cdot \sigma(\mathfrak{p}))^{\text{min}(a_i,b_i)}$. But $\mathfrak{p}\cdot \sigma(\mathfrak{p})$ is an integer, and even a prime ! It divides $a$ and $b$ so it divides $c$.
Hence we have proved that each prime factor in $\overline{c}$, or product of two of them (in the second case) divides $c$ with at least the same multiplicity. So by Gauss lemma we can conclude that $\overline{c}$ divides $c$. As you already noticed that $c$ divides $\overline{c}$, the proof is complete.
